# Filename casing changed to lower when argument for Python Glob module is taken from list

Tags: python, windows, glob

I have Python list with filenames ("filename_mask_list"), and I need to search some root Directory and its Sub-directories to find files, which match my filenames, in order to copy them to some common directory.

I have used pathlib.Path.glob to serach recursively directories:

```
from pathlib import Path
filename_mask_list = ['DEU.FourSeasonsHotelsandResorts.csv', 'DEU.Hilton.csv', 'DEU.Hertz.csv']
for searched_file in filename_mask_list:
    for searched_path in Path('C:\root_dir').glob('**/' + searched_file):
        print(searched_path)
```

With above code, the found filename in printed "searched_path" is in lower case. If I use direct option to instead of passing element from list as search criteria the casing is preserved:

```
for searched_path in Path('C:\root_dir').glob('**/DEU*.csv'):
    print(searched_path)
```

I need to preserve filename casing of copied files, because having it in lowercase will cause dependent processes to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `glob.glob` will give you the file names with the same case as in the search criteria. I don't know the reasons for this apparent inconsistency.

```
import glob
filename_mask_list = ['DEU.FourSeasonsHotelsandResorts.csv', 'DEU.Hilton.csv', 'DEU.Hertz.csv']
for searched_file in filename_mask_list:
    for searched_path in glob.glob('C:\root_dir/**/' + searched_file, recursive=True):
        print(Path(searched_path))
```

Note that I preserved your spelling `'C:\root_dir'` for clarity but it is most lilely wrong.

Comment: Thank You for support. The option without "Path" worked fine. My root paths in Python list were Windows style paths e.g. "D:\2019.09\EUR" and I have used forward slash in my search pattern. But it worked except the lower casing of filenames. BTW: do You have idea why my question was down-voted? Was it unclear, stupid etc?

Comment: @zwornik I downvoted the question because, as obvious as it was, I didn't realize it was about windows. I couldn't undo it without editing the question so I added the `Windows` tag and reversed my vote.

Comment: Just adding pitfall for the unwary: searched_path matches the case of the search term NOT the actual case of the found file! So the problem (I would say bug) in pathlib's glob and rglob returning incorrectly lower-cased results is not solved by switching to glob.